# Update age column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a user table with the user's **birthday** (YYYY-MM-DD) as well as **age**. I want to run a script to calculate *and* update the age column nightly via cron.

This SQL works well for selecting and calculating the age:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - 
    DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '%Y') - 
    (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '00-%m-%d')) AS age
FROM 
    `jos_jcourse_students`
```

But is it possible to **update** the age column with a single statement? Tried the following, but all I managed to do was populate the age column with all 0s! Do I need to use some sort of MySQL loop?

```
UPDATE 
    `jos_jcourse_students` 
SET 
    age = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - 
    DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '%Y') - 
    (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '00-%m-%d')) AS age
FROM 
    `jos_jcourse_students`"
```

Comment: you have tried this query at once?

Comment: The age column seems redundant here.  Any reason you couldn't get rid of it altogether, and calculate the age as needed?  Not like it's that complicated of a calculation... :)

Comment: yeah, could have got rid of it, but it's already been programmed that way so don't want to change the db structure ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE `jos_jcourse_students` 
SET age = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(birthday)), '%Y')+0
```

OR according to your logic it will be

```
UPDATE `jos_jcourse_students` 
SET age =((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '%Y')) - 
    (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '00-%m-%d')))
```

Comment: seems to work - what am I missing by using this shorter calculation vs. the original one?

Comment: calculation is ok. You don't need to use update select ... it will be ok with just using update

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE 
    `jos_jcourse_students` 
SET
    age = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - 
    DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '%Y') - 
    (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '00-%m-%d')) AS age
FROM 
`jos_jcourse_students`)
```

Comment: i guess i forgot the last bracket...please try now

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve the above result by using the self join technique. i.e join to the same table using its unique id (primary key example studentId)

```
UPDATE jos_jcourse_students a, 
      ( SELECT studentId, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '00-%m-%d')) AS age
        FROM `jos_jcourse_students`) b
SET a.age = b.age
WHERE a.studentId = b.studentId
```

Note: **studentId** is primary key in jos_jcourse_students